# Computer starts, ubuntu asks username and password, and then "freezes"

Tags: password

I've just installed the version 12.04 of ubuntu, and the installation was succesfull, then it asked me to restart computer, everything normal, but when it started again, ubuntu asked for username and password, and then, after I typed them and entered, instead of showing the desktop, it's just showing the default rainbow like picture of ubuntu.
I can move the mouse fluidly, everything seems normal but it's just waiting there, doing weel, nothing.
So i thought about switching off, and when pressing the button, it asked me "are you sure you want to switch off?" which, I believe, was kind of strange cause it was "frozen-like".

So what should i do now ? is there anything like the task manager on ubuntu ? or something i could open to see what's wrong ?

PS : first time using ubuntu

Bye

Comment: I suspect it is a Video driver problem. What is your video card? ATI? Nvidia?

Answer (score 0):

If you press Ctrl+ALT+T, you will get a terminal. Type in there:`gnome-system-monitor` and see what's using the RAM and CPU.

Comment: ctrl+T won't work ..?! no terminal or whatsoever opens

Comment: And now some window saying the languages weren't well installed or something, i have no idea what the hell is going on

Comment: have you thought of disk problems?

Comment: i'm going to try to recreate a CD tomorrow
Thanks for your help people !